# Moving personal belongings to Italy

Tags: italy, shipping, customs

I lived in the USA for over 30 years. I am a resident of Italy for over 10 years.
I just came back to the States for sending my belongings kept in storage in Chicago.
I contacted many international shipping companies requesting a 20' container to transport my items from Chicago to my house in Italy.
They all seem to have a problem with me, being a resident of Italy. They all think that it's a relocation and I need to fill out a Relocation Form supplied by the Italian Consulate.
I am already a resident!!!!! They don'y seem to understand.
Where can I find an International shipping company that would provide me with a container, fill it up and ship it door-to-door to Italy without problems?

Comment: You say you are a "resident" of Italy. Are you an Italian citizen?

Comment: In my (limited) experience, relocations are typically exempted from import duties.  It is probably in your financial interest not to go out of your way to avoid characterizing the shipment as a relocation.

Answer (score 1):

You are relocating your personal belongings.  The belongings are yours now and will still be yours after shipping.  Therefore, you should use a relocation form.

Someone I know used a regular shipping company to ship her stuff from the US to the UK, rather than a moving company with a relocation company.  Upon arrival, she had to pay significant import duties.  I relocated my stuff with a relocation company from Canada to the UK (when it was still in the EU) and paid no import duties.  But — there was no consulate involved; the shipping form was provided by the moving company.

The fact that your stuff moves 10 years later than you do doesn't matter.